# drupal, tree in search form

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules

I want to make a search result page based on eBay/allegro, by that i mean:

1. left box -> category (with hit count)
2. center -> table with hits.

it should looks like that: (left box is most important)
[image: it should look like that]

And now, my current modules/Content types looks like that:

Content Types:

**Content Taxonomy Fields** - taxonomy used with CCK. this is must have for me. My node types is based on that.

Modules (all for drupal 6.22):

- [Content Construction Kit (CCK)](http://drupal.org/project/cck)
- [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)
- [fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) + [votingAPI](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi)
- [Content Taxonomy](http://drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy)
- [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)
- [Faceted Search](http://drupal.org/project/faceted_search)
- [CCK Facets](http://drupal.org/project/cck_facets)
- [Faceted Search Context](http://drupal.org/project/fs_context)

And i don't know what to do... I can't figure that out :| 
Any ideas, would be great !

Thx 
Lukasz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky task. There are always many ways to accomplish it.
If it was me, I would write my own module from scratch. Having it interface with views will be a little complicated.
Just to give you some starting tips:

- In the main view, you need to either add an exposed form where you can select the category AND/OR an argument to filter the selected categories.
- Then create another view that lists taxonomy terms.

  - The easy task would be to link the category name to the main view passing the category tid just rewriting the output as a link.
  - Then place the view inside a block and have the block show next to the main view OR use panels to combine both views somehow.
  - It's gonna be tricky to add the counts, if you can't find a module to do so, you could either theme the field to add the count or use http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield
  - The real deal would be to group and indent the categories, I'm not sure you can group taxonomy temps.

If you are to write your module, maybe you can take a look at http://drupal.org/project/tagadelic

Comment: Actually I used Faceted Search module. 
This one allows you to create block containing (almost) everything i wanted while on search result page. (after a little change from: http://drupal.org/node/753074)